# How do I get TIFF tags from a JPEG file only using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, metadata, jpeg, tiff, cmyk

I'm currently allowing people to upload an image to my application, but am in need of extracting metadata for JPEGs.
How do I check for a JPEG image's value for its  value?

I need to do this with javascript because images above 120MB will cause OOM in my backend, so would rather load this image in JS and check for its metadata to see if it's in RGB or CMYK.

Comment: There's probably a module on npm to do this. Try spending some time searching for an API.

Comment: https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

Answer (score 0):

There is single metadata standard for JPEG. You are going to have to be able to handle several, including JFIF, Adobe, and Exif. Will first have to find the format being used by looking at the APPn markers.Then you will have to process the markers depending upon the type. There is no avoiding have to read those standards.